# Using Django Templates to get data from the database in Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

So I am using AJAX to get a response on a form data submitted. I initially used to do it using an HTTP request but then due to other reasons, I shifted to using AJAX where I am thrown with several errors.

So firstly from my views.py, I send a JsonResponse back to JS.

```
data = list(Trips.objects.all().values())
return JsonResponse({"noOfTrips":len(data), "trip":data})
```

And now previously my template.html looks like this...

```
<a class="text-decoration-none text-dark ModalSelector" id="linkTripModalBtn" data-bs-target="#linkTripModal">
            <div class="passengerTripListCont font3 p-2 mt-2">
                <div class="row1 d-flex align-items-center container-fluid px-0">
                    <img class="rounded-circle mx-2" width="50" height="50" src="{{trip.user.profiledriver.your_picture.url}}" alt="profPic">
                    <div>
                        <p class="mb-0"><strong class="driverName">{{trip.user.first_name}} {{trip.user.last_name}}</strong> (#<span class="driverID">{{trip.user.id}}</span>)</p>
                        <small class="text-muted"><span class="driverVehicle">{{trip.vehicle_used.model}}</span> <strong>{{trip.vehicle_used.vehicle_number}}</strong></small><br>
                        <small>Trip refernece: #<strong class="tripID">{{trip.id}}</strong></small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row2 mt-2 border-top border-dark pt-1">
                    <p class="text-center mb-1 travelPoints d-flex align-items-center">
                        <span class="tripDeparture">{{trip.departure}}</span>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle mx-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 8a7 7 0 1 0 14 0A7 7 0 0 0 1 8zm15 0A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM4.5 7.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h5.793l-2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708L10.293 7.5H4.5z"/>
                        </svg> 
                        <span class="tripArrival">{{trip.arrival}}</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="row3">
                    {% if tripsUserData.period == None %}
                        <h6 class="text-center">Travelling <strong class="tripDate">{{trip.date}}</strong> at <strong class="tripTime">{{trip.time}}</strong></h6>
                    {% else %}
                        <h6 class="text-center">Travelling <strong class="tripDate">{{tripsUserData.period}}</strong> at <strong class="tripTime">{{trip.time}}</strong></h6>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="row4 d-flex justify-content-around">
                    <p class="px-2 rounded-pill d-flex align-items-center bg-light">
                        <span class="tripTakenSeats">{{tripsUserData.taken_seats}}</span>/<span class="tripVacantSeats">{{trip.vacant_seats}}</span>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-people-fill mx-2" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M7 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 5-4 5 3 5 4-1 1-1 1H7zm4-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z"/>
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.216 14A2.238 2.238 0 0 1 5 13c0-1.355.68-2.75 1.936-3.72A6.325 6.325 0 0 0 5 9c-4 0-5 3-5 4s1 1 1 1h4.216z"/>
                            <path d="M4.5 8a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5z"/>
                        </svg>
                    </p>
                    <p class="px-3 bg-light rounded-pill">
                        Rs. <span class="tripPrice">{{trip.price_per_person}}</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
```

Where I want to know once I get the Query output as a JSON response, how can I perform certain actions such as `{{trip.user.last_name}}` and `{{trip.vehicle_used.vehicle_number}}` since these are linked to different tables as well and I only get the ID of each table...

So how can I go through such a problem in the most efficient manner?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

**EXTRA**

Just in case you wanted to see my models.py..

```
class Trip (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) #Drivers Profile
    departure = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    departureCoord = models.OneToOneField(Coordinates, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="departureCoord", blank=True, null=True)
    arrival = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    arrivalCoord = models.OneToOneField(Coordinates, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="arrivalCoord", null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(validators=[inthe_future])
    time = models.TimeField(default=datetime.now().time())
    vacant_seats = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    vehicle_used = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price_per_person = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, default='UPCOMING', max_length=10)
```

Comment: You can use class or id selector to change values i.e :  `$(".driverName").text(return response ..)`

Comment: Hey @Swati, i don't exactly understand what you mean, could you please elaborate on that a bit more or post it as an answer please

Comment: Show your ajax code .Also , you have mutliple such div or only one which you have posted in question ?